# Документирование кода. Как использовать gtk-doc?

Tags: c, gtk

Имеется код созданный на основе GObject который необходимо задокументировать, обнаружил, что для этой цели есть gtk-doc, который способен кроме описания функций еще документировать сигналы и свойства объекта. 
Использовал это: https://wiki.gnome.org/DocumentationProject/GtkDoc и это https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-doc-manual/stable/ .
Документация должна собиратся "make doc".

Вопрос как создать рабочий Makefile?

Makefile:

```
objects =   main.o example_person.o
source  =   main.c example_person.c
bin = main
DOC_MODULE = example_person


CC=gcc 
CFLAGS = -g -O0 --std=gnu99 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter \
$(shell pkg-config --cflags gobject-2.0)

LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs gobject-2.0)

ALL_FLAGS = $(CFLAGS) 
ALL_LIBS  = $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)


$(bin): $(objects)
    $(CC) $(ALL_LIBS) -o $(bin) $(objects)

$(objects): $(source)
    $(CC) $(ALL_FLAGS) -c $(source)



clean:
    rm -f $(bin)
    rm -f *.o

// Создание документации "make doc"
doc:
    @echo "doc generator ... "

    # sources have changed

    gtkdoc-scan --module="$(DOC_MODULE)" 
    gtkdoc-scangobj --module="$(DOC_MODULE)" --output-dir=gen --cc="$(CC)" --cflags="$(CFLAGS)" --ldflags="$(LIBS)"
    gtkdoc-mkdb --module=$(DOC_MODULE) --output-format=xml --source-dir=src

    # xml files have changed

    mkdir html
    cd html && gtkdoc-mkhtml $(DOC_MODULE) ../meep-docs.xml
    gtkdoc-fixxref --module=$(DOC_MODULE) --module-dir=html
```

Comment: Посмотрите как это реализовано в autotools. Там наверняка есть готовые цели и макро для этого.

Comment: autotools usage:     gtkdoc-scangobj [-h] [--version] --module MODULE [--types TYPES]
                       [--type-init-func TYPE_INIT_FUNC]
                       [--query-child-properties QUERY_CHILD_PROPERTIES]
                       [--output-dir OUTPUT_DIR] [--cc CC] [--ld LD]
                       [--cflags CFLAGS] [--ldflags LDFLAGS] [--run RUN]
                       [--verbose]

Comment: Объясните как пользоваться.

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-doc-manual/stable/settingup.html.en

Comment: А, вот для простого случая без Autotools: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-doc-manual/stable/plain_makefiles.html.en Вы видимо просто скопировали этот пример без понимания как это работает внизу. Там в документации 2 глава начинается с иерархии каталогов и названий модулей в терминах gtk-doc. И да, у вас-то и вопроса нет, непонятно что у вас не получается, какие ошибки выводятся и пр.

Comment: Вопрос состоит в следующем, как создать Makefile для создания документации при помощи gtk-dok, без использования autotools и др., простой пример Makefile.